Search-and-replace in a macro failing stops macro
I've got an issue where about 16 nuget packages were renamed, so I'm faced with going through about 50 project.json files in 50 different directories and fixing the names of any of these 16 nuget packages that are in that file.
I'm trying to do this by creating a kbd macro, and using replace-string 16 times (once for each possible replacement). However, any time that string does not exist in the file, macro recording ends. I could make a training buffer in scratch with all the patterns for recording the macro, but I suspect macro execution will also end in any buffer upon the first instance of any of those 16 strings (nuget packages) not existing in that buffer.
Is there a way to do what I want in a macro? A reasonably easy way?
A comment asked for more details, so here's what the macro looks like in the emacs last-kbd-macro editor:

Command: last-kbd-macro
Key: none

Macro:

ESC
xreplace-string     ;; self-insert-command * 15
RET         ;; newline
std.config      ;; self-insert-command * 10
RET         ;; newline
std.multilib.config ;; self-insert-command * 19
RET         ;; newline
        ;; beginning-of-buffer
ESC
x           ;; self-insert-command
            ;; previous-line
RET         ;; newline
std.containers      ;; self-insert-command * 14
RET         ;; newline
std.multilib.containers ;; self-insert-command * 23
RET         ;; newline
        ;; beginning-of-buffer
ESC

...

There are 15 or so repeats of this pattern. I believe the problem is that if "replace-string" doesn't find the string its looking for in the buffer I happen to be in, it rings the bel and macro recording terminates. AFAIK, there isn't a single buffer that has all 16 patterns I might need to replace.

It might help if you showed your code/recipe so far.

@Drew - Thanks for commenting, mainly for reminding me I'd posted this. Got coding-brain-fog and forgot.

@Drew - Edited into the question.

I've just tested in a few versions (as far back as 27.2), and for me M-x replace-string doesn't signal an error or otherwise inhibit macro replay if there's nothing to replace.

@phils Replay, no. However it does end the recording if there's nothing to replace while you are recording.

Another good idea (this would honestly probably be THE answer) would be to use the macro editor. Since each of the 16 strings I need to find and fix differ only in the search and replace strings, it would probably be easiest to just record the macro for the first one, then yank out 16 copies of that sequence in the macro editor, replacing the search and replace strings on each one.

I can't reproduce your problem -- when I tested, I recorded a macro which firstly tried to replace-string for a string which didn't exist in the buffer, and then secondly replace-string for a string which did exist.  The macro was recorded in full, and I could replay it successfully.

I tried the idea I mentioned in the question: putting a copy of everything I needed to replace in the scratch buffer. This actually worked. I was able to record the entire macro, since all the patterns I needed existed in the scratch buffer. When the macro executes, not finding one of the patterns in the buffer I happen to be in did not terminate execution of the macro.
I'm still interested if anyone has an alternate solution to this issue. I could see situations where this hack I came up with would not be feasible.

You can append to the current keyboard macro (effectively, resume recording) by typing the universal prefix C-u before your macro-recording keystroke -- I think it's F3 by default; I re-bound it for myself to F6 decades ago for reasons I no longer remember.
Whether that would solve your issue I can't say for sure, but at first glance it seems like it might.

Would probably be tricky in this case, because typing the other stuff needed correctly as if it had found the search string without an actual search hit as a guide would be a feat. I suppose I could have gone and found a buffer that would work for... Still this is a great tip in general, particularly for when I mess up near the end of a long macro recording.

Although ... all I guess I do after that in this case is go to the top of the buffer and start looking for the next string. I'll think on this one, but upvote for a good answer no matter what.
